# Play sound while button is pressed

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Morning all,

I'm trying to play a sound while a button is pressed. Not on just a 'Click', but play the sound as long as the button is pressed upon and stop the sound when the button is released.

I mated the sound to the button in Blend but I don't see a button option in blend that allows the sound to play ONLY while the button is pressed on. All I see available in the button options is 'Click'.

Any ideas on how I can do this in code or Blend?

Thanks so much.

EDIT - Here is the code Im trying but no luck:

```
<MediaElement Name="mp1" Source="Assets/media/mysound.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />

private void button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
mp1.Play();
}

private void button1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender,System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

mp1.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keydown event, and start the audio.

And then stop it when keyup event is fired.

The events can be done in blend, but as far as I know you can only make the start in blend. And not the stop. If you do it and paste the code with your two events and the start music I can quickly do the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks JTIM, is that something I can do in blend? The stopping when the event is fired?

Comment: @user3460731 I have updated my answer with the info. But No not everything can be done by blend

Answer (score 0):

You can add the music file to your project and use a combination of keydown event and mediaelement playback. Stop/Pause mediaelement media on keyup.